# PostgreSQL failing peer authentication with Ansible

Tags: postgresql, authentication, freebsd, ansible

I am running PostgreSQL 9.3 on FreeBSD. FreeBSD uses `pgsql` as the default system user for PostgreSQL. My `/usr/local/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             pgsql                                   peer
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

With this configuration I can connect to the database as `pgsql` without a password.

```
$ su pgsql
$ psql template1
template1=# \l
                         List of databases
...
```

That works as intended.

On a remote machine, I have an Ansible task to create a database on the FreeBSD server.

```
- name: Create the postgresql database
  postgresql_db: name=mydatabase login_user=pgsql
```

Executing this task fails with the error `Peer authentication failed for user "pgsql"`.

```
PLAY [web] ********************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [host.example.org]

TASK: [database | Create the postgresql database] *****************************
failed: [host.example.org] => {"failed": true}
msg: unable to connect to database: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "pgsql"


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Why does this fail when peer authentication for the user `pgsql` is clearly working?

Comment: Do you have to run the ansible module as the `pgsql` user? eg, add: `sudo: true` and `sudo_user: pgsql` to your command

Comment: Have you eventually find out any solution to this?

Answer (score 66):

This worked for me:

```
- name: Create postgres database
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_db:
    name: <database-name>
```

In your specific case the user might be `pgsql`, but I think usually the user is `postgres`.

Answer (score 23):

Or with slightly different syntax (from Ansible 1.9) and for user creation (might be helpful for someone)

```
- name: Create postgres user
  postgresql_user: name={{ pg_user }} password={{ pg_password }}
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
```

Comment: Ansible < 1.9: `sudo: yes; sudo_user: postgres`

Answer (score 21):

For those running into "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create..." in order to switch to the `postgres` user with `become_user` you can leverage pipelining on Ubuntu hosts.

Create a `ansible.cfg` in your playbook directory and add the following lines:

```
[ssh_connection]
pipelining=True
```

**Update:** according to @lolcode Ansible 2.9.0 has updated to `ansible_pipelining`

```
   [ssh_connection]
   ansible_pipelining = true
```

**Update 4/30/2020:** for those who still have issues, try installing `acl` which will cause Ansible to use this acl filesystem to mount module that need to be accessible by the 2nd user instead of making them readable by everyone. Thanks @Andreas Florath

```
- name: install setfacl support
  become: yes
  apt: pkg=acl
```

Comment: Thanks for saving hours of my life :)

Comment: No problem! Countless others have done the same for me. Pass it forward.

Comment: The pipelining = True answer worked for me  but on ansible 2.9.0 the format has changed to `ansible_pipelining = true` as per [this ansible issue][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31125#issuecomment-333847610

Comment: This did not work for me. I needed to install the acl tools as described: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646880/ansible-2-1-0-using-become-become-user-fails-to-set-permissions-on-temp-file/36681626

Comment: @DylanPierce Note that you spelled `ansible_pipelining` a bit wrong in your edit (you wrote `piplining`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the 2020 update. I have no idea about postgresql and stuff, just trying to cobble something together. Without the hint about `acl` I feel like this would have become a very, very long search... so, much <3

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. In my case I overlooked that I configured my Ansible-playbook to run as another Linux user than the one with peer access (pgsql in your case). Solution is either run the Ansible play as pgsql:

```
- name: Create the postgresql database
  remote_user: pgsql
  postgresql_db: name=mydatabase login_user=pgsql
  ...
```

Or run it as root, and su to pgsql for the command:

```
- name: Create the postgresql database
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  become_user: pgsql
  postgresql_db: name=mydatabase login_user=pgsql
  ...
```

... depending on your access rights via ssh.

This is using Ansible 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround is to connect via `host` (localhost) rather than the default `local` peer authentication method:

```
- name: Create the postgresql database
  postgresql_db:
    name: mydatabase
    login_user: postgres
    login_host: 127.0.0.1
```

Depending on the settings in `pg_hba.conf`, you may also need to provide `login_password`. You can circumvent this by setting

```
host    all         postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

to

```
host    all         postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Comment: You helped me indirectly. I was using     login_host: "{{ item.login_host | default('localhost') }}". Switching to default('omit') solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I notice your Postgres version is really out of date (9.3). I had this issue recently when working on an Ubuntu 14 server with Postgres 9.3.

I tried a dozen different things, and finally what worked was installing the `acl` package via apt. Ansible uses it for navigating some of it's permissions issues. The package is installed by default on newer distros, hence why I've only seen this problem crop up on an old server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this threat I made a variant of mdh's post. When I set up a database I generate a password for the postgres user and I store it in a file under the root directory.

I thought why not store it also (or instead) in a .pgpass file for root. So I created a template like this (only last line is important):

```
#### password file for posgres connection ###

#### *:*:*:*
#### works like
####    *      :      *    :     *     :     *
#### <ip addr> : <port nr> : <db name> : <password>

127.0.0.1:*:*:postgres:{{ new_postgres_pass }}
```

Store the .pgpass file in the home directory of root. Now you can use the module as root without switching user of having to change the pg_hba.conf:

```
- name: Ensure postgresql mydatabase
  postgresql_db:
    name: mydatabase
    login_user: postgres
    login_host: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have sudo (debian, etc) but have access to root

```
- name: Create database
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  become_method: su
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_db:
    name: my_db
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem due to postgres authentication methods configured at **/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf** , the configuration location may vary depending on the version installed, **/etc/postgresql//main/pg_hba.conf**

```html
sample ansible recipe
---
- name : "Dump PostgreSQL database"
  gather_facts: true
  hosts: posgre_host
  tasks:
    - name: Dump existing PostgreSQL database
      community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
        name: demo
        state: dump
        target: /tmp/backup/backup.sql.gz
      become: true
```

From

```
local           all           postgres           peer
```

To

```
local           all             postgres        trust
```

Here trust authentication method anyone connect to the server is authorized to access the database, since ansible is working based on ssh, it is safe to change.

Answer (score -4):

So if I understood well you are on a remote machine, and maybe you should change /usr/local/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf to allow remote connections 'host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5' or another specific network address.