# Ansible 2.1.0 using become/become_user fails to set permissions on temp file

Tags: git, vagrant, ansible, sudo, ansible-2.x

I have an ansible 2.1.0 on my server, where I do deployment via **vagrant** and on PC too.
The role "deploy" have :

```
- name: upload code
  become: true
  become_user: www-data
  git: repo=git@bitbucket.org:****.git
     dest=/var/www/main
     key_file=/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa
     accept_hostkey=true
     update=yes
     force=yes
 register: fresh_code
 notify: restart php-fpm
 tags: fresh_code
```

In this case with ansible 2.1.0 I get an error:

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user. For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}
```

It it ansible 2.0.1.0 which I use on my PC, is all normally - folder /var/www/ have folder main with owner and group www-data

If I use only became_user: www-data and if I use become_method: sudo with became_user: www-data - i got same error

What need to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that `www-data` cannot access the same files your default non-root ansible user created you use to connect to the machine. Also the error message clearly points to [ansible's documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user) which describes what options you have to fix this issue when upgrading from ansible 2.0 or below.

They suggest three ways to properly fix the issue:

> - Use pipelining. When pipelining is enabled, Ansible doesn’t save the module to a temporary file on the client. Instead it pipes the module to the remote python interpreter’s stdin. Pipelining does not work for non-python modules.
> - Install filesystem acl support on the managed host. If the temporary directory on the remote host is mounted with filesystem acls enabled and the setfacl tool is in the remote PATH then Ansible will use filesystem acls to share the module file with the second unprivileged instead of having to make the file readable by everyone.
> - Don’t perform an action on the remote machine by becoming an unprivileged user. Temporary files are protected by UNIX file permissions when you become root or do not use become. In Ansible 2.1 and above, UNIX file permissions are also secure if you make the connection to the managed machine as root and then use become to an unprivileged account.

Or if you cannot do any of these fixes, then you can force ansible to run in a bit more insecure way (which seemed to be the default in ansible 2 and below), which should also fix your problem, but would not fix the underlying security risk:

> If you can’t make any of the changes above to resolve the problem and you decide that the machine you’re running on is secure enough for the modules you want to run there to be world readable you can turn on `allow_world_readable_tmpfiles` in the `ansible.cfg` file. Setting `allow_world_readable_tmpfiles` will change this from an error into a warning and allow the task to run as it did prior to 2.1.

Comment: Thank you for replay. For me help second answer. I installed acl-tools and that resolve problem. In playbook I use  `become: true  become_user: www-data` and all going well

Comment: Installing the `acl` module on Debian servers (Option 2) was by far the easiest option for me, and this also works if you have "leave temp files on server" enabled for debugging.  I gave up on getting Ansible pipelining working (OS X 10.11 client, Debian 7 servers, tried various config file changes but nothing worked).  I also found that using the "connect as root" option ran into an unrelated bug where most of the playbook was silently skipped.

Comment: If you get these hard-to-Google symptoms when using the "connect as root" technique with `--ask-become-password` (option 3), the root cause is this issue - just install the `acl` module to fix them:  "Playbook asks for sudo password and uses it to sudo (you get a password error if mis-typed) but then exits without error after the [setup] implicit task (which appears to succeed)".  Seems like an Ansible 2.1.0 bug.

Answer (score 47):

On debian/ubuntu you can resolve this by first installing the `acl` package on the remote host, like with this ansible task:

```
- name: install setfacl support
  become: yes
  apt: pkg=acl
```

Same thing with redhat/centos -- install the `acl` package on the remote host:

```
- name: install setfacl support
  become: yes
  yum: name=acl
```

Comment: Does this require changes to the `fstab` or a reboot?

Comment: Did not require a reboot in my case.

Comment: On RHEL6, acl is not enabled by default. After installing the `acl` package, we can add the "acl" option to `/etc/fstab`, and/or run e.g. `sudo mount -o remount,acl /` to enable it immediately.